# C++ makefile with relative include path to parent

Tags: makefile, g++

I've got a working project that I need to take parts from it without changing it's code and just write new main() for it.
My directory structure:

[main_dir]/[main.cpp]

[main_dir]/[dir1]/[child1]/file1.h

[main_dir]/[dir2]/[child2]/file2.h

in main.cpp I have: include "dir1/child1/file1.h"

In file1.h I have:  include "dir2/child2/file2.h"

I'm compiling: 
g++ main main.cpp

I'm getting "dir2/child2/file2.h" no such file or directory.
I can't change file1 to do: include "../../dir2/child2/file2.h"

Somehow in the original project something in the makefile to search for all include path relative to the [main_dir] so the include from file1.h can be found.

What should I add to the makefile in order to do it as well?

Comment: `g++ -o -l main main.cpp` doesn't look correct. First of all the `-o` option needs the name of the output file directly after it. Secondly what is the `-l` option? Is it lower-case L, or upper-case i?

Comment: Edited, both of them probably not needed right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using double-quotes to include a header file, as in

```
#include "dir2/child2/file2.h"
```

then the compiler will use the directory of the ***current*** file to search for the header file.

If you have it in your `file1.h` then the compiler will look for the header file `[main_dir]/dir1/child1/dir2/child2/file2.h`. Which isn't correct.

You can solve it by telling the compiler to add `[main_dir]` to the list of standard include search paths. This is done with the `-I` (upper-case i) option:

```
g++ -I [main_dir] main.cpp
```

Then when the compiler fails to find `dir2/child2/file2.h` in its first search, it will continue with the list of standard include search paths, and it should be found.

Answer (score 2):

You need to manage `CPPFLAGS` in your `Makefile`.

```
CPPFLAGS="-I[main_dir]"
```

And compile application with receipt like this:

```
g++ $(CPPFLAGS) main.cpp -o main
```

Also it's recommended to read make style guides to write a good one `Makefile`. You can meet there tips for include folders declaration.